# Deployment to ESP8266 with ESP Open SDK

Tags: c++, c, esp8266

I want to be doing C/C++ development with the ESP8266 using my favorite editor at the time (VS Code). Don't want to be using the Arduino IDE. I have the ESP Open SDK up and running and all, but find it rather annoying having to be flashing every time I want to deploy. Takes about 30 seconds getting both images across. This is a horrific feedback loop for me.

Before I head off writing my own Socket server that can take binaries and reflash while running or similar..   This must be a solved problem.. ??

Comment: I believe I might have found the answer. Not quite familiar with all the terminology in this space yet. But the term I was looking for; Firmware Over-The-Air. Something this project provides through its own firmware; https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlatformIO, which bills itself as an "an open source ecosystem for IoT development" has integration with VS Code.

Instructions for VS Code are at: http://platformio.org/get-started/ide?install=vscode

You can use this instead of the Arduino IDE.